# Access is denied in GAE in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

When I try to call `Model.put()` in Eclipse for a Google Python app, I get the following error:

```
exception value:[Error 5] Access is denied
```

I don't know if it's related, but this happened after I changed the parameter of --`datastore_path="F:/tmp/myapp_datastore"` in arguments of debug configurations.

Everything is working fine for another application from the command prompt. 
However, when I use the same in Eclipse I get following dump in the console window of Eclipse:

```
ERROR    2009-06-11 10:19:41,312 dev_appserver.py:2906] Exception 
encountered handling request 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools 
\dev_appserver.py", line 2876, in _HandleRequest 
    base_env_dict=env_dict) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools 
\dev_appserver.py", line 387, in Dispatch 
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools 
\dev_appserver.py", line 2163, in Dispatch 
    self._module_dict) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools 
\dev_appserver.py", line 2081, in ExecuteCGI 
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools 
\dev_appserver.py", line 1979, in ExecuteOrImportScript 
    script_module.main() 
  File "F:\eclipse\workspace\checkthis\src\carpoolkaro.py", line 749, 
in main 
    run_wsgi_app(application) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext 
\webapp\util.py", line 76, in run_wsgi_app 
    result = application(env, _start_response) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext 
\webapp\__init__.py", line 517, in __call__ 
    handler.handle_exception(e, self.__debug) 
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext 
\webapp\__init__.py", line 384, in handle_exception 
    self.error(500) 
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable 
INFO     2009-06-11 10:19:41,312 dev_appserver.py:2935] "POST /suggest 
HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

This is the screen dump of the application from a browser window:

```
 F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp 
\__init__.py in handle_exception(self=<__main__.SuggestHandler object 
at 0x019C0510>, exception=WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied'), 
debug_mode=True)
```

Comment: Definitely need more details. Does f:/tmp/myapp_datastore exist? Is it writable?

Comment: WARNING  2009-06-10 20:19:11,717 datastore_file_stub.py:404] Could not read datastore data from C:\DOCUME~1\abc\LOCALS~1\Temp"

It is working fine from normal direct access using command prompt but problem is only in eclipse environment. Does APTANA does something in eclipse because it was working well before that? not sure.

Comment: Yes its writable as I have manually created a file in same folder hiearchy and later changed back datastore path to temp

Comment: F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py in handle_exception(self=<__main__.SuggestHandler object at 0x019C0510>, exception=WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied'), debug_mode=True)

Comment: Can you please update your question with full stacktraces and extra details?

Comment: I have removed aptana manually, even then the problem persists

The following warning comes when the app is launched by eclipse in debug mode.
WARNING  2009-06-11 08:38:47,687 datastore_file_stub.py:404] Could not read datastore data from F:\tmp\myapp_datastore

Comment: 382       debug_mode: True if the web application is running in debug mode
  383     """
  384     self.error(500)
  385     logging.exception(exception)
  386     if debug_mode:
self = <__main__.SuggestHandler object at 0x0161F4D0>, self.error = ''
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'str' object is not callable 
      args = ("'str' object is not callable",) 
      message = "'str' object is not callable"

Comment: cannot exceed 600 characters so sharing the link http://tinyurl.com/l2n5b4

Answer (score 1):

According to this error,

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I guess, you have shadowed built-in object `str` to something else.

For example, you used `str="dummy"` in your code and `str` became uncallable object.

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 generally means the path you specified is wrong. I recommend you to remove the double quotation marks in your command:

Try:

```
--datastore_path=F:/tmp/myapp_datastore
```

and let us know if that helped you